# How to give the x y position to image control at runtime in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, translate-animation

I have set the canvas in Background and adding some image pieces as a child of that background canvas, now i want to move the specific image control to given x y position of background canvas so i have tried this kind of code given below

bg_Canvas.Children[it].RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();

```
            TranslateTransform trans = bg_Canvas.Children[it].RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();

            animation.To = 80; 
            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, trans);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.XProperty));

            Storyboard story = new Storyboard();
            story.Children.Add(animation);


            story.Begin();
```

it's working but the problem is moving image control could not be placed at a correct x position of background canvas , it's been taking x position from where image placed, actually 0th x position starts from image control placed on the canvas so i need to set the x position of background canvas for image control to be placed. how can i correct this problem please tell me the solution for this if anybody known.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using translation, simply tell the canvas where to place the image:

```
Canvas.SetTop(image, 80);
Canvas.SetLeft(image, 160);
```

Edit: To allow you to animate elements, you can read up about `Storyboard` - when you use it, in the property to animate, put `"(Canvas.Left)"` or `"(Canvas.Top)"` appropriately.

If you are using WP8, you can modify the code posted [in this series of posts](http://socialeboladev.wordpress.com/2013/03/01/different-approach-for-animation-in-xaml-using-net-4-5-new-async-functionality-part-1/) to work on Windows Phone (it was coded for Windows 8). It makes animating stuff (including on canvas) very easy.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply, i want to move the each image pieces to given x y position of background canvas. Moving Operation should be done, so please tell me the solution for that.

Comment: Moving of Each image pieces should be done by one by one at particular time, so how to do that?

Comment: Edited and added info on what you will need to look up.